# how to dismiss a keyboard when there is no textfield to resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, uitableview, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

[image]

in the following scenario clicking on the pencil turns the iz 1 text to be editable by making it `becomeFirstResponder` and the keyboard opens, I wish to close the keyboard when clicking on the "empty rows" or iz2.

how can i do that?

I've tried adding to the cellView

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self dismissKeyboard];
}
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can hide keyboard using this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

**EDIT**

Add gesture in where you can call `becomeFirstResponder`.

```
- (void)showKeyboard
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hide)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

and remove it in hide method,

```
- (void)hide
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.view.gestureRecognizers[0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Or:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathForYourCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    YourCustomCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForYourCell];

    [cell.iz1TextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: the above does work, probably your -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event wasn't called at all?

Comment: @liva can you set a breakpoint in `touchesBegan:` to see if it is called?

Comment: where do you place the code in the `viewcell` or `tableviewcontroller`? because the cell doesn't have self.view so i wrote `[self endEditing:YES]` and the functions is being called

Comment: Try calling: `[cell.iz1TextField resignFirstResponder]`. You can access this text view by getting a cell using `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: when i place the code in the uitableviewcontroller it doesn't get called

Comment: Try placing it in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

my final solution was something similar to what @caglar suggested here is the code i've written inside `tableviewcontroller`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```